# How to copy contents of one file and paste before a specified string using windows batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have two files with some contents. Sample contents are shown below.

Destination file:

```
<TypesCatalogue><Type><ClassName>RuleID</ClassName><PackageName>com.fentbase.types.primitives</PackageName><ParentType>FEBAALong</ParentType><JavaType>Long</JavaType></Type><Type><ClassName>TranRequestEntityId</ClassName><PackageName>com.fentbase.types.primitives</PackageName><ParentType>FEBAAString</ParentType><JavaType>String</JavaType></Type><Type><ClassName>HostCriteriaVO</ClassName><PackageName>com.fentbase.types.valueobjects</PackageName><ParentType>IFEBAValueObject</ParentType></Type></TypesCatalogue>
```

Source file:

```
<Type><ClassName>HostCriteriaVO</ClassName><PackageName>com.fentbase.types.valueobjects</PackageName><ParentType>IFEBAValueObject</ParentType></Type>
```

The contents of source file should be inserted before `</TypesCatalogue>` in destination file.

Comment: Poison characters and foreign characters and xml without line breaks will all change the way this task is approached.  To give you code that doesn't break we'd need to see the actual contents of the file to see if those things need to be handled.

Comment: Edited the question to sample file contents.

Comment: There is no `</TypesCatalogue>` in the source file in your example

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, sorry editing mistake. Updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "destination=" < destination.xml
set /P "source=" < source.xml
set /P "=!destination:</TypesCatalogue>=%source%!</TypesCatalogue>" < NUL > newDestination.xml
```

If the result is correct, just remove the "new" part from output file.

Comment: This works if the file contents are less. If destination file is big, there seems to be some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Test this: it creates `newfile.xml`

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
type destination.xml|repl "</TypesCatalogue>" "" L >newfile.xml
type source.xml >> newfile.xml
>>newfile.xml echo ^</TypesCatalogue^>
```

Comment: @naveenbharadwaj Is there a reason why you have not commented?  You were posting when I added my answer.